# Asked one well-recieved question, but second similar question was closed and downvoted

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked a question yesterday about an octagon mask in CSS. I understood that construction, but today I asked a question about icosagon mask. It got 10 down votes and also got closed. Why did this happen?

My question from yesterday: [How can I create Octagonal mask in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28030659/how-can-i-create-octagonal-mask-in-css)

Today's question: (Deleted; 10k+ only) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046973/is-icosagon-mask-possible-in-css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The close reason (just under your question) was:

> "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Your question isn't clear about what you tried - there is some CSS (using `clip-path`) but it is entirely unclear whether that's just a sample you grabbed from somewhere, whether it has a problem, and if so, what it is.

Comment: I created it using clippy tool. > http://www.bennettfeely.com/clippy/
I wanted just some assistance, not the answer. but it got closed.

Comment: I had tried everywhere on Google, and then asked this question. @Oded Please tell me whether this question deserved to be closed?

Comment: If you don't tell people what you tried and what the code has to do with your question (in particular - what works, what doesn't work and where you are stuck), they can't really know. You didn't do those things, so the question got closed.